# Chinese translate

Tags: translation, traditional-characters, seal, calligraphy

It’s a watercolor painting from my sister many years ago I just want to know what is say[image]

Comment: maybe “灕江風光己巳年xx画”?

Answer (score 1):

It's the title of the painting.

Looks like "漓江风光, 己巳年, 晓晗画"

漓江江风光 means the view/scenery of Li River, which is a famous river in Guilin, southwesten China.

己巳年 is a Chinese traditional way of numbering years. For example, 1869,1929,1989,2049 are all numbered as 己巳年.

晓晗 is the author's name.

画 means painted.

So together, it means:

This painting shows the great view of Li River. 晓晗(Xiao Han) painted at the year 1989(or 1929?)